# Can't compile using gulp

Tags: npm, sass, gulp, yarnpkg, gulp-sass

Whenever I try and run either `yarn install` or `npm install` I get:

```
libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_values.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/source_map.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/subset_map.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_c.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_value.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/units.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/utf8_string.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/util.o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/values.o
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/jordan/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node -I/Users/jordan/.node-gyp/16.13.1/src -I/Users/jordan/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/jordan/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/jordan/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/uv/include -I/Users/jordan/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/zlib -I/Users/jordan/.node-gyp/16.13.1/deps/v8/include -I../../../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o ../src/binding.cpp
In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
In file included from ../../../../nan/nan.h:58:
In file included from /Users/jordan/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/node.h:63:
In file included from /Users/jordan/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8.h:30:
/Users/jordan/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'remove_cv'?
            !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
                                ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
                                     remove_cv
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:776:50: note: 'remove_cv' declared here
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_cv
                                                 ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/jordan/Sites/statement/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/jordan/Sites/statement/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jordan/Sites/statement/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I've tried everything, removing the package.json, reinstalling node, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that `node-gyp` is failing because it cannot find the expected version of the C++ compiler on your machine. You may fix thix by (re-)installing the XCode Command Line Tools as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-macos).
Typically, all you should need to do is running:

```
xcode-select --install
```

And follow the wizard instructions.